# TemporalData Properties

Tags: time-series

Reading and testing a question&answer from this place I found the following:

```
values = 100 + 
  RandomFunction[ARProcess[{0.7}, 1], {1, Length@dates}][
    "States"][[1]]
```

as I try to identify parts of this instruccion meet the `["States"]` it must be one of the properties of a `TemporalData`, but can not found in the list of notes of `TemporalData`, neither it appears when doing

```
RandomFunction[ARProcess[{0.7}, 1], {1, Length@dates}][
        "Properties"]
```

as indicated in the note. I tried even to enter some other option not listed as

```
RandomFunction[ARProcess[{0.7}, 1], {1, Length@dates}][
            "Green"]
```

and of course appeared a mistake,  so not anything is possible in thes position but not only those that appear in list or Properties, How to know more as "States", where can found theese extra options ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I misunderstood the question. Didn't realize you wanted the undocumented properties.

Some digging gave me this:

```
Cases[DownValues@RandomProcesses`TemporalDataDump`iProperty,
   HoldPattern[
     RandomProcesses`TemporalDataDump`iProperty[p_String, ___]] :> p,
   \[Infinity]
   ] // DeleteDuplicates // Sort

{"ACFPlot", "Caller", "DateFunction", "DateList", "DatePath", \
"DatePaths", "Dates", "DatesQ", "DeveloperProperties", "Drop", \
"FirstDate", "FirstDates", "FirstTime", "FirstTimes", "FirstValue", \
"FirstValues", "LastDate", "LastDates", "LastTime", "LastTimes", \
"LastValue", "LastValues", "MaximumTime", "MetaInformation", \
"MinimumTime", "MinimumTimeIncrement", "NormalizedPathTimes", \
"NormalizedTimes", "NumericMinimumTimeIncrement", "ObjectType", \
"Options", "PACFPlot", "Part", "Path", "PathComponent", \
"PathComponents", "PathCount", "PathFunction", "PathFunctions", \
"PathLength", "PathLengths", "PathMinimumTimeIncrement", "Paths", \
"PathTimeIndex", "PathTimes", "Properties", "RawStateCount", \
"RawStates", "RawTimes", "RawTimesCount", "ResamplingType", \
"SliceData", "SliceDistribution", "StateSpace", "StructuredPath", \
"StructuredPaths", "Take", "TemporalDataPath", "TimeIndex", \
"TimeList", "Times", "TimeSpace", "UnexpandedRawTimes", \
"UnexpandedRawTimesList", "UniformlySpacedQ", "Version"}
```

And then your `"States"` is in:

```
TemporalData[{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}}]["DeveloperProperties"]

{"ACFPlot", "Caller", "Components", "DateFunction", "DateList", \
"DatePath", "DatePaths", "Dates", "DatesQ", "DeveloperProperties", \
"Drop", "FirstDate", "FirstDates", "FirstTime", "FirstTimes", \
"FirstValue", "FirstValues", "LastDate", "LastDates", "LastTime", \
"LastTimes", "LastValue", "LastValues", "MaximumTime", \
"MetaInformation", "MinimumTime", "MinimumTimeIncrement", \
"NormalizedPathTimes", "NormalizedTimes", \
"NumericMinimumTimeIncrement", "ObjectType", "Options", "PACFPlot", \
"Part", "Path", "PathComponent", "PathComponents", "PathCount", \
"PathFunction", "PathFunctions", "PathLength", "PathLengths", \
"PathMinimumTimeIncrement", "Paths", "PathStates", "PathTimeIndex", \
"PathTimes", "Properties", "RawStateCount", "RawStates", "RawTimes", \
"RawTimesCount", "ResamplingType", "SliceData", "SliceDistribution", \
"StateDimensions", "States", "StateSpace", "StructuredPath", \
"StructuredPaths", "Take", "TemporalDataPath", "TemporalDataPaths", \
"TimeIndex", "TimeList", "Times", "TimeSpace", "UnexpandedRawTimes", \
"UnexpandedRawTimesList", "UniformlySpacedQ", "ValueDimensions", \
"ValueList", "Values", "Version"}
```

---

This works for me:

```
TemporalData[{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}}]["Properties"]

{"Components", "DateList", "DatePath", "DatePaths", "Dates", \
"FirstDates", "FirstTimes", "FirstValues", "LastDates", "LastTimes", \
"LastValues", "Part", "Path", "PathCount", "PathFunction", \
"PathFunctions", "PathLength", "PathLengths", "Paths", "PathTimes", \
"SliceData", "SliceDistribution", "TimeList", "Times", \
"ValueDimensions", "ValueList", "Values"}
```

Comment: Yes, this is same I receive with ["Properties"] but does not appear States.. it means have more properties than those in the expresion...

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. I can give a somewhat better answer, but I don't think it likely that there will be a standard list of these.

Comment: Any opinion is welcome, I think maybe is old version (suported option) ...

Comment: Strong and deep! Thanks you just gave me reason to learn a lot. I read about you like to discover inside ... undocumented ...  EURISKO!